# Making a 64 modem pool work on Ubuntu

Tags: modem

I have a 64 port siemens wavecom modem pool connected via USB to a Computer running Ubuntu. I am trying to create a python script that interacts with the modems for some automated testing project but Ubuntu can only detect 32 devices. Is there any way I can increase the number of modems it can detect?

Answer (score 1):

Believe it's compiled into the kernel.

```
grep CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS /boot/config*
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS=32
```

See [Serial Tips And Miscellany](http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-15.html)

> Number of Serial Ports Supported
>   If you have more than 4 (or possibly 2) serial ports, then you must insure that the kernel knows this. It can be done by configuring the kernel when compiling or by a parameter given to the kernel when it starts (boot-prompt or kernel command line).
>
> The kernel configuration parameters: CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS=4 and CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_NR_UARTS=4 set the maximum number of ordinary serial ports (UARTs) equal to 4. If you have more than 4 ordinary serial ports, then you need to change the 4 to whatever. But you may override this via the kernel command line for example: nr_uarts=16 (if serial support built into the kernel) or 8250.nr_uarts=16 (if serial support is via a module). The boot loader such as lilo or grub can be told to do this.